# Acceder a valores en listas anidadas en python

Tags: python

estoy empezando con python y tengo una duda que creo que es muy simple pero no consigo resolverla con intuición.

Tengo una lista con listas anidadas como la siguiente:

```
["February",9.9, 14.3, 5.4, 35, 70],
["March", 11.8, 16.1, 7.4, 36, 70],
["April", 13.7, 18.0, 9.4, 40, 69],
["May", 16.9, 21.1, 12.8, 47, 70],
["June", 20.9, 24.9, 16.8, 30, 68],
["July", 23.9, 28.0, 19.8, 21, 67],
["August", 24.4, 28.5, 20.2, 62, 68],
["September", 21.7, 26.0, 17.4, 81, 70],
["October", 17.8, 22.1, 13.5, 91, 73],
["November", 13.0, 17.3, 8.6, 59, 71],
["December", 10.0, 14.3, 5.7, 40, 69]]
```

los datos corresponden a temperaturas medias, maximas mínimas,... Mi intención es usar estos datos para una representación gráfica. Por ejemplo para representar la temperatura media quiero coger la posición [1] de todos los elementos de la lista para obtener el dato de temperatura media de todos los meses. La manera simple que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

`media = meteo[0][1], meteo[1][1], meteo[2][1], meteo[3][1], meteo[4][1], meteo[5][1], meteo[6][1], meteo[7][1], meteo[8][1], meteo[9][1], meteo[10][1], meteo[11][1]`

Así creo una lista con los datos que me interesan, pero me parece muy poco "pythonico", he probado con expresiones tipo "meteo[0:11][1]" pero no sale el resultado que busco. Alguna idea? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien tu problema es que no te gusta como estas planteando esta linea

```
media = meteo[0][1], meteo[1][1], meteo[2][1], meteo[3][1], meteo[4][1], meteo[5][1], meteo[6][1], meteo[7][1], meteo[8][1], meteo[9][1], meteo[10][1], meteo[11][1]
```

Lo que puedes usar es ["comprehension"](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html) y quedara bastante mas limpio

```
media = [i[1] for i in meteo]
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En una lista de listas, para obtener los datos de una columna tienes dos opciones:

- Usar un for que itere sobre las filas e indizado:

  ```
  temp_medias = [row[1] for row in meteo]
  ```
- Usar `zip`:

  ```
  meses, temp_medias, *_ =  (list(col) for col in zip(*meteo))
  ```

  Tiene más sentido si quieres obtener todas las columnas o al menos varias a la vez.

`datos[0:11][1]` lo que hace es un rebanado (slicing) de las filas de la primera  a la undécima `[0:11]` y luego de ellas toma la segunda fila(la fila de `Febrero`)

Si fuera un array de NumPy si podrías hacer :

```
temp_medias = meteo[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias FjSevilla, había visto algo de la función zip pero no entendía muy bien como funcionaba. Ahora me queda más claro, las dos soluciones que planteas son válidas, además de la opción de convertir la lista en un array y usar la expresión que comentas:

```
meteo = np.array([["February",9.9, 14.3, 5.4, 35, 70],
["March", 11.8, 16.1, 7.4, 36, 70],
["April", 13.7, 18.0, 9.4, 40, 69],
["May", 16.9, 21.1, 12.8, 47, 70],
["June", 20.9, 24.9, 16.8, 30, 68],
["July", 23.9, 28.0, 19.8, 21, 67],
["August", 24.4, 28.5, 20.2, 62, 68],
["September", 21.7, 26.0, 17.4, 81, 70],
["October", 17.8, 22.1, 13.5, 91, 73],
["November", 13.0, 17.3, 8.6, 59, 71],
["December", 10.0, 14.3, 5.7, 40, 69]])

temp_medias = meteo[:, 1]
```

Muchas gracias!